# User relations in database issue with design

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, database-design

```
UserRelations{UserID, FriendID, RelationStatus}
```

And there are users with ID's 1,2,3 etc.
User 1 send request to user 2
User 3 send request to user 1
So in database I have:

```
1 | 2 | 1
```

and

```
3 | 1 | 1
```

Now I have a little confusion to write query (maybe design is wrong).
I need to get list of all friends based on userID. But user can be in two columns based on that if he requst relation or someone request relation from him.
If I use this query I get all users who request relation from me, but I get and a list of users that I have sent relation requests, but profile datada that I get is mine and not from that user.

```
select ur.*, p.FirstName, p.LastName
from userRelations ur
join Profiles p on ur.UserId = p.UserId
where ur.FriendId = @UserId or
ur.UserId = @UserId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just missing a join to profiles on `FriendId`:

```
select ur.*, p1.FirstName, p1.LastName, p2.FirstName, p2.LastName
from userRelations ur
join Profiles p1 on ur.UserId = p1.UserId
join Profiles p2 on ur.FriendId = p2.UserId
where ur.FriendId = @UserId or ur.UserId = @UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a **UNION** query to get friends going in both directions instead of using an OR operator in the WHERE clause, like so:

```
select               -- Get people you friended.
  ur.UserID          -- ME (i.e. the @User)
, ur.FriendID        -- The other person.
, ur.RelationStatus
, p.FirstName
, p.LastName 
from userRelations ur                    
inner join Profiles p on ur.FriendId = p.UserId
where ur.UserId = @UserId
--
union all
--
select               -- Get people who friended you.
  ur.FriendID        -- ME (i.e. the @User)
, ur.UserID          -- The other person.
, ur.RelationStatus
, p.FirstName
, p.LastName 
from userRelations ur                    
inner join Profiles p on ur.UserId = p.UserId
where ur.FriendId = @UserId
```

Notice how the columns in each select, the joins and each where clause change to reflect the perspective of the friendship direction for each half of the UNION.